# onSurfaceChanged method called when soft keyboard is shown

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

When soft keyboard is shown, onSurfaceChanged method is called with wrong size and breaks my image capture function.

I tried below workarounds (from other stackoverflow questions) but still doesn't work:

- Add android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
- Add android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustSize"

Other non-desirable options:

- Add a variable to prevent subsequent onSurfaceChanged call.
- Change layout when soft keyboard is shown.

I'm looking for a clean & easy solution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found simple solution for this is adding below line to Android Manifest:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

onSurfaceChanged doesn't get called 2nd time. In addition, the surface is pushed up when soft keyboard is shown, which I like better.